# Rust: Type must be rooted

Tags: rust

What is the meaning of this Rust compiler error? I get it encountering:

```
pub fn some_func(foo: Something<Else>) -> Another {
    Another { foo: foo }
}
```

yields error:

```
error: Type must be rooted
  --> script/foo.rs:12:32
   |
12 |     pub fn some_func(foo: Something<Else>) -> Another {
   |                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: `#[deny(unrooted_must_root)]` on by default
```

Comment: Please include the full error and enough code to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an error that is specific to a compiler plugin used by [the Servo project](https://github.com/servo/servo/). It refers to the requirement that types that are under the control of the JavaScript GC must have a root present on the stack to ensure that it is safe to use them in a given stack frame, which will prevent the value from being GCed while it is in use by Rust code.